# Начало использования слова «эрос» в русском языке

Tags: выбор-слов

Если верить графику [РусКорпоры](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/plot.xml?smoothing=3&stat=gr_created_&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%FD%F0%EE%F1), то слово «эрос» начали использовать в русском языке только в самом-самом конце XIX века. Насколько можно верить в таких вопросах РусКорпоре и есть ли какие-то словари, в которых указано, с какого времени то или иное слово вошло в язык?

Comment: Не надо никому верить. И менее всего - источеику, о котором никто не знает. Как считали, какая выборка... Без этого обсуждать красивости графика не имеет смысла. Опять же, "эрос" и Эрот - разные слова, как их считать-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-видимому, это слово встречалось и раньше.

[Исторический словарь галлицизмов русского языка приводит и другие примеры,отсылающие к середине 19 века](http://gallicismes.academic.ru/)

> ЭРОС, ЭРОТ а, м. гр. Eros (Erotos). С прописной буквы (. В древнегреческой мифологии - бог любви в виде крылатого ребенка с луком (в древнеримской мифологии - Купидон). БАС-1
> Кругом летят Эроты, игры - И гимны в честь ему поют. Пушк. Торжество Вакха. Блажен, кто веселится В покое без забот, С кем втайне Феб дружится И маленький Эрот. **Пушк.**
>
> Городок. || перен., устар., разг. Чувственность. В этих chambres garnies всегда пахнет помадой, духами, все комнаты носят будуарный характер .. эротом так и несет отовсюду. Атава Оскудение. // ОЗ **1880 7 1 183.** Если искусство вообще недалеко от любви (эроса), то музыка .. к ней всех ближе. А.Фет Кактус. // РВ 1881 11 233. - Лекс. Толль **1864**

Comment: Эрот (с заглавной)  и эрос (нарицательное) - разные слова. Обсуждать на примерах из Пушкина не имеет смысла.

Comment: Что означает "Лекс. Толль"?

Comment: В приведенных цитатах со строчной получается только 1880 год, а не середина XIX века.

Comment: Нашел [словарь Толля](http://www.bookva.org/books/268), издания 1864 года, там действительно в третьем томе на с. 1122 есть «эротика» и прочие однокоренные слова.

Comment: Лекс. Толль -словарь Толля, вы правильно нашли.

Answer (score 0):

Уточните вопрос, если не трудно. 
Тут ведь действительно вопрос о том, что "Эрот" использовался задолго до Пушкина - в условно-нарицательном значении (т.е. с заглавной, но не как имя конкретного божества, а иносказательно, как имя "подведомственного" ему "чувства".  Ну а нацкорпус, вестимо, считает "эрот" и "эрос" словами разными.

Это по поводу вашего "графика". Ну а касательно собственно вопроса: от Жуковского как минимум. А то и от Ломоносова, он языки знал. Нацкорпус почти не содержит текстов того времени.  Естественно, что число вхождений сильно зависит лот общего объема текстов.

Comment: Меня интересует эрос/эрот как существительное, а не как имя собственное.